# Kernel exception log understanding

Tags: exception, linux-kernel, arm, powervr-sgx

I am getting an exception like

```
------------[ cut here ]------------
WARNING: at kernel/workqueue.c:806 wq_worker_waking_up+0x74/0x88()
Modules linked in: dc_incdhad1(OF) pvrsrvkm(OF) corelockr(OF) topazkm(OF) vdecdd(OF) imgvideo(OF) tty_hci(F) st_drv(F) wl12xx(F) wlcore(F)
CPU: 1 PID: 277 Comm: kworker/u8:2 Tainted: GF          O 3.10.60 #13
Workqueue: pvr_workqueue MISRWrapper [pvrsrvkm]
Stack : 8de85380 80685fd0 8009f7a4 00000326 8068af7c 8077ee40 80715d00 81c08e40
      80715cfc 805d7638 80685fd0 800a5bf0 80715d00 00000000 806b193c 8df33bfc
      8df33bfc 8de85380 80685fd0 800a0bd4 80688620 00000000 00000151 802eb040
      00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 5f727670 6b726f77
      75657571 00000065 00000000 00000000 8ea35280 8e848100 c1a5a07c 8df33ba8
      ...
Call Trace:
[<8005d420>] show_stack+0x64/0x7c
[<800811d4>] warn_slowpath_common+0x78/0xa8
[<8008128c>] warn_slowpath_null+0x18/0x24
[<8009f7a4>] wq_worker_waking_up+0x74/0x88
[<800b35cc>] ttwu_do_activate.constprop.80+0x60/0x80
[<800b58ec>] try_to_wake_up+0x1d4/0x348
[<805dc44c>] __mutex_unlock_slowpath+0x3c/0x54
[<c1a73098>] DisableSGXClocks+0x58/0x108 [pvrsrvkm]
[<c1a72d00>] SysDevicePrePowerState+0x44/0x54 [pvrsrvkm]

---[ end trace f8733685011c8bb9 ]---
```

Is there any way to read this log, and to reach a definite conlcusion. This log changes in the next boot, but first 5 lines remains same.

Comment: Looks like the error is coming from PowerVR SGX kernel module. Try to rebuild that module against the kernel you are using. Maybe this is just some sort of inconsistency between module version and kernel version.

Comment: Well, apparently [something's unexpectedly waking up on the wrong CPU](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/kernel/workqueue.c?h=v3.10.60#n806), whatever that entails...